# Should I care about dynamodb stream shards if I process stream events by lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

The [dynamodb documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) says that there are shards and they are needed to be iterated first, then for each shard it is needed to get number of records.

The documentation also says:

> (If you use the DynamoDB Streams Kinesis Adapter, this is handled for you: Your application will process the shards and stream records in the correct order, and automatically handle new or expired shards, as well as shards that split while the application is running. For more information, see Using the DynamoDB Streams Kinesis Adapter to Process Stream Records.)

Ok, But I use lambda not kinesis (ot they relates to each other?) and if a lambda function is attached to dynamodb stream should I care about shards ot not? Or I should just write labda code and expect that aws environment pass just some records to that lambda?

Answer (score 2):

When using Lambda to consume a DynamoDB Stream the work of polling the API and keeping track of shards is all handled for you automatically.  If your table has multiple shards then multiple Lambda functions will be invoked.  From your prospective as a developer you just have to write the code for your Lambda function and the rest is taken care for you.

In-order processing is still guaranteed by DynamoDB streams so with a single shard will have only one instance of your Lambda function will be invoked at a time.  However, with multiple shards you may see multiple instances of your Lambda function running at the same time.  This fan-out is transparent and may cause issues or lead to surprising behaviors if you are not aware of it while coding your Lambda function.

For a deeper explanation of how this works I'd recommend the YouTube video [AWS re:Invent 2016: Real-time Data Processing Using AWS Lambda (SVR301)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFLKOy4GKXQ).  While the focus is mostly on Kinesis Streams the same concepts for consuming DynamoDB Streams apply as the technology is nearly identical.

Comment: Is it possible to force creation of more shards? I am having a major throughput issue with the stream data. I can write a massive amount into the table but the event stream appears to be pegged at a relatively low rate compared to how fast I'm writing into the table. My partition key is essentially a random uuid so I'm not sure how to make it have more shards.

Comment: You could temporarily scale up your writes to very high levels to force your partitions to split, but be warned this will impact the ability to read and write items and not just the streams. You'd need to set above 3,000 read or 1,000 write to force your first shard to split in two. Alternatively the best practice is to fan out to other Lambda functions by invoking asynchronously if performing the work isn't performant.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. The actual numbers are a bit opaque I think. I am using auto-scale on this table but I may actually just bump it up high manually and then let it auto-scale back down after wards.

I am considering the lambda fan out but I'm a little afraid of infinite looping there. Have to be careful. I am even considering just slamming them into another kinesis stream which I can control the shards over, say set it to 16 manually or something. Right now I'm realizing that another lambda I have is processing faster so I'm going to try to optimize the actual code in the lambda first.

Comment: Ok just optimizing my lambda seemed to help immensely. I was taking the 1000 record batch and then sending 1000 items into CloudSearch. Now I'm breaking it into groups of 100 and sending then to cloud search in parallel... now its keeping up with the incoming writes. I didn't realize it but apparently the lambda itself was the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

We use DynamoDB to process close to billion of records everyday and autoexpire those records and send to streams.

Everything is taken care by AWS and we don't need to do anything, except configuring streams (what type of image you want) and adding triggers.

The only fine tuning we did is,

When you get more data, we just increased the batch size to process faster and reduce the overhead on the number of calls to Lambda.

If you are using any external process to iterate over the stream, you might need to do the same.

**Reference:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: what batch size are you using? Also, the table stream seems to be very slow for me or pegged at a single shard perhaps, how can I increase the number of shards to increase the number of parallel lambdas invoked by the stream?

Comment: Our batch size is 100. We don't do any business logic with those messages, we use it to distribute from there. I don't see there is a way to invoke parallel lambdas from streams.